# Syntax highlight feature for Grunt-ngdocs

Tags: angularjs, syntax-highlighting, jsdoc

I don't know whether something is going wrong or it's not supported yet, but I expect to see code blocks like:

````
```
var example = 3;
```
````

in documentations to be highlighted.
How can I fix/add this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Workaround:

*marked* module is used in *grunt-ngdocs* (`grunt-ngdocs\node_modules\marked\lib`).
Since `grunt-ngdocs` uses *angular-bootstrap-prettify* (which BTW uses *google-code-prettify*), it's enough to tweak *marked* a little in order to produce `<pre class="prettyprint linenums">...</pre>` instead of `<pre>...</pre>`. 
So at `Renderer.prototype.code` function (line 757 at my version), return statements can change like this:

- `return '<pre class="prettyprint linenums"><code>' ...`
- `return '<pre class="prettyprint linenums"><code class="' ...`

## Cleaner solution:

*ngDocs* seems to replace all `<pre>..</pre>` blocks with `<pre class="prettyprint linenums">...</pre>` (line 266 at v0.2.6). So instead of using markdown ```` ``` ```` code ```` ``` ```` blocks, we can use `<pre>...</pre>` blocks directly at documentations.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) and [jQuery livequery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/)

My ngdocs section in Gruntfile.js now looks like this:

```
options: {
  html5Mode: false,
  scripts: [
    'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'js/jquery.livequery.min.js',
    'angular.js',
    'js/helpers/ngdocs.js',
    'bower_components/highlightjs/highlight.pack.js'
  ],
  styles: [
    'bower_components/highlightjs/styles/atelier-forest.dark.css'
  ]
```

And my js/helpers/ngdocs.js looks like this:

```
'use strict';

/* global $, hljs */
$(function () {
    $('pre code').livequery(
        function() {
            hljs.highlightBlock(this);
        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I myself came up with a solution quite similar to this (except for using angularized version of hljs). Then by exploring ngdoc.js and docs.js from grunt-ngdocs, I camed up with a better solution which I'm gonna describe in a separate answer.